# Python: Assigning the second value from a line of output to variable

Tags: python, list

I have the following lines of `python` code

```
import subprocess
buckets = open('permissions.txt', 'r')
for x in buckets:
   get_version = ['gsutil', 'versioning', 'get', x]
   get_version = subprocess.check_output(get_version)
   print (get_version)
   if get_version == "Enabled":
       print "Versioning already enabled on" (x)
   else:
       version_on = ['gsutil', 'versioning', 'set', 'on', x]
```

The output of the `print` from line 6  `print (get_version)` is as follows:

```
   gs://xxxxxxx.appspot.com: Enabled
   gs://xxxxxxxx_cloudbuild: Enabled
```

I want only the second value to be assigned to the variable `get_version` from the above output which is `Enabled` so that it can be compared with `if` statement on the next line of `code`

I tried with below code but I think it works with comma separated values only

```
  get_version = subprocess.check_output(get_version)[1]
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What happens when you `print(get_version)` after `get_version = subprocess.check_output(get_version)[1]`?

Comment: `if get_version.split()[-1] == 'Enabled'` should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want only the second value to be assigned to the variable get_version from the above output which is Enabled

According to [the documentation for `check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

> subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False, universal_newlines=False)
>
> Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

The return value is a single string, so there is no "second value". You need to parse the string to get the characters that you want.

> I tried with below code but I think it works with comma separated values only

> ```
> get_version = subprocess.check_output(get_version)[1]
> ```

This is a decent attempt. However, it gives the second **character** in the string, which isn't what you want. Instead, you need to do a little more work. In this case, you need the `split()` function to parse the "words" from your string:

```
results = get_version.split()
```

Now you can index `results`:

```
print(results[1])
```

I suggest you familiarize yourself with [the standard string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) so you know what tools are available when you need them.

Unsolicited advice:

Look at this code for a moment:

```
   get_version = ['gsutil', 'versioning', 'get', x]
   get_version = subprocess.check_output(get_version)
```

Here you reuse the same variable to mean different things. In general, this is not a good idea because when you come back to this code later, it can be confusing. I suggest you come up with two separate names that describe exactly what each thing is:

```
   command = ['gsutil', 'versioning', 'get', x]
   output = subprocess.check_output(command)
```

Then my above solution becomes:

```
results = output.split()
print(results[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your additional suggestions on the best practices.